# How to define zero joint state reference value in URDF/XACRO?

Tags: urdf, xacro, robot-description

When defining the robot URDF/XACRO file we set links and joints.
By default the joints states are zero on spawning.

Is there a way to redefine the reference value of the joints states, essentially offsetting it to the proper coordinate system?